# How to get direct access to polygons in VTK?

Tags: vtk

I found [this post online](https://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2013-January/078000.html) (dates back to 2013) when I had trouble getting direct access to a specific cell in a `vtkPolyData`. I am using the latest version: `VTK 8.1.1` and it seems like the newer version of VTK still has this issue.

```
polys->InitTraversal();
for(int i = 0; i < polys->GetNumberOfCells(); i++)
{
    polys->GetNextCell(idList); // This sequential method gets the point IDs correctly
    int a = idList->GetId(0);
    int b = idList->GetId(1);
    int c = idList->GetId(2);
}
```

However, the direct access method seems to have issues

```
polys->InitTraversal();
for(int i = 0; i < polys->GetNumberOfCells(); i++)
{
    polys->GetCell(i, idList);    // This method returns wrong ids
    int a = idList->GetId(0);
    int b = idList->GetId(1);
    int c = idList->GetId(2);
}
```

How can I get the point IDs in a specific cell without looping through all the cell? Isn't `polys->GetCell(i, idList)` meant to give you direct access to a specific cell?

Comment: Please check if my answer works for you ( and accept it if it does :-) ).

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well as the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For direct access, we can use [vtkPolyData::GetCellPoints()](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyData.html#a3259703dfd28ad92c88a84adac00e725) method. For example we can do

```
vtkNew<vtkIdList> idL; // or auto idL = vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList>::New();
poly->GetCellPoints( 13, idL ); // Assuming you want the points for 13th cell
for(auto i = 0; i < idL->GetNumberOfIds(); ++i)
    std::cout<< idL->GetId(i) << std::endl;
```

For looping over all cells I prefer a `while` loop:

```
vtkNew<vtkIdList> idL;
poly->GetPolys()->InitTraversal();
while(poly->GetPolys()->GetNextCell(idL)){
    for(auto i = 0; i < idL->GetNumberOfIds(); ++i)
        std::cout<< idL->GetId(i) << std::endl;
}
```